# Broken margins on review page

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, design

Looks like there is something wrong with margins on [review pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits):

> [image: main review page]

> [image: reviewed item]

Comment: @Adam this fix probably broke design on ruSO. See my reports on ruSO.Meta: [one](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6516/176217), [two](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6517/176217).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fixed now:

> [image: fixed]