# Processing a suggested edit in popup wraps buttons

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, suggested-edits, popups

If suggested edit have been opened via “edit (1)” link under the post body then buttons will be displayed in two rows without a normal alignment:

> [image: 2 rows]

Same edit opened within review queue displayed correctly:

> [image: 1 row]

This happens due to changing working window width. In popup view width is smaller.

[Same design issue](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6516/176217) occurs in Stack Overflow in Russian, but for items opened in review queues because of the longest words in the buttons.

Seems this issue is related to [another bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304101/339911) that already fixed.

Comment: [Me too](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11027/191178), except I've only seen it on ELU.

Comment: [Not as bad as on Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3337/52050)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed, perhaps as part of the [review queues redesign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346902/295232). The Skip button is no longer shown, and the wraparound doesn't occur anymore:

[image]