# Enhance the review mechanism on mobile app

Tags: feature-request, review, ios-app

Currently it is quiet cumbersome to come to do reviewing on the mobile app. IMHO especially reviewing is something people could / would do in every free minutes they have e.g. due the meeting or waiting time on the doctor. By putting a link or icon prominently on the entry site, it would enhance the reviewing activity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I report bugs with or request features for the Stack Exchange mobile app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348075/how-can-i-report-bugs-with-or-request-features-for-the-stack-exchange-mobile-app)

Comment: They're [working](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346902/295232) on making the pages responsive, but you should note that reviewing on a small screen is hard anyway, and we'd like to pay reviewers as much attention as they can.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Well if you take a look at the *first post* and *late answer* review, there are quite often small amount line task. Sure it would increase skipping, still better than nothing. For others tasks, you are right, one needs bigger display. But the mobile phone also getting bigger display. Anyway I know that there is no support for the app, so my question is answered.